# File.exists shows file even when it does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, file-io

I am checking if a file exists, and if it does, I put it in a list, otherwise I remove from the list. My code is so:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
{
    _savedxml.Add(kvp.Key.ToString());
}

string namewithext=null;
for (int i = 0; i < _savedxml.Count; i++)
{
    namewithext = string.Concat(_savedxml[i], ".xml");
    System.IO.FileInfo file_info = new System.IO.FileInfo((string)namewithext);
    long size = file_info.Length;
    if (size == 0)
    {
        _savedxml.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < _savedxml.Count; i++)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(namewithext)))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        _savedxml.Remove(namewithext);
    }
}
```

I've tried many ways, but even though a file does not exist, the list contains it. I've probably made a silly error.

How can I do this?

Comment: what is the return value of `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(namewithext)` ? where does this file reside (network share...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in the code:

- You set the `namewithext` variable for each item in the first loop, then use it in the second loop, so you will be checking if the last file exist over and over.
- When you remove an item, the next item takes its place in the list, so you will skip the check for the next item.
- You are checking the length of the files before checking if the files exist, so you will get a `FileNotFoundException` when you try to get the length for files that doesn't exist.

Corrected (and some cleanup):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict) {
  _savedxml.Add(kvp.Key);
}

for (int i = _savedxml.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  string namewithext = _savedxml[i] + ".xml";
  if (!System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(namewithext))) {
    _savedxml.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}

for (int i = _savedxml.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  string namewithext = _savedxml[i] + ".xml";
  System.IO.FileInfo file_info = new System.IO.FileInfo(namewithext);
  if (file_info.Length == 0) {
    _savedxml.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that the use of RemoveAt(i) in the middle of a loop is still a bad practice (even if going down). I would use a new empty list and add to it the valid names...  (but still vote up (-: )

Comment: @RoeeGavirel: Yes, that is one way. Using `List<T>.RemoveAll` is another. I just didn't want to change the code too much from the original. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code that I can spot:

1. Getting the Length property of a FileInfo instance that refers to a file that doesn't exist should throw an exception, not return 0.
2. In the second for-loop you iterate over your savedxml list, yet you never change the "namewithext"-variable, which would cause you to try and remove the same entry every time.

**EDIT**
Additionally, Duncan is right, of course, if the code inside the "if (size == 0)" branch would ever run, you'd skip an entry in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing an item from your collection by index, which will then change the position of the remaining items in your collection.  It will then end up skipping an entry which it should have removed.

Answer (score 0):

`_savedxml` has file names without extesnion, so before `_savedxml.Remove(namewithext);` remove extesnion from `namewithext`.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
{
    _savedxml.Add(kvp.Key.ToString());
}

string namewithext = null;

int i = 0;

while (i < _savedxml.Count)
{
    namewithext = string.Concat(_savedxml[i], ".xml");
    System.IO.FileInfo file_info = new System.IO.FileInfo((string)namewithext);
    if (!file_info.Exists || file_info.Length == 0)
        _savedxml.RemoveAt(i);
    else
        i++;
}
```